# VBA & MS Excel 2010 Run-time error '13'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I have got a project from a colleague. When I try to run a macro, I get the error 'Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch'

Any ideas what could be causing this? The code that is causing it in VBA is:

```
Worksheets("Model").Range("A" & i + 5).Value = Worksheets("Model").Range("A" & i + 5).Value + rating * Worksheets("parameters").Range("E" & paramerange).Value
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the value of i and paramerange to an whole number value? I can be 0 in your formular but Paramerange must be a positive whole number.

You can check the different parts of the line to try to find the error.

```
Sub TestLine1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim rating As Integer
Dim Paramerange As Integer
rating = 2
Paramerange = 13
i = 1

MsgBox(Worksheets("Model").Range("A" & i + 5).Value)
MsgBox CStr(Worksheets("Model").Range("A" & i + 5).Value + rating * Worksheets("parameters").Range("E" & Paramerange).Value)


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I is set to 1 and paramerange is set to 13

Comment: I've run your code without gettin an error, try the code I have put in the eddited answer to try to locate the problem.

Comment: I have noticed that the numbers they are comparing as being stored as type 'General' but they have leading 0's, in one sheet they are being cut off and in the other they aren't. Am I able to store them both as type Text of would that cause problems?

Comment: You could give it a try, but I would have thought that it's best to store numbers as numbers.